# Selecting a random value from vector but excluding particular values

Tags: matlab, random

I thought this was an easy one but I cannot find any solution for it.

I have this vector called `cues= ["R" "B" "C" "P" "Y" "G"];`
from which I want to randomly select one value, but excluding one (or two) of the values each time.

For example, I would like to get a random value from the vector excluding the `"R"` value, or in a second condition I would like `"R"` and `"Y"` not to be selected from the sample.

I have tried using `randsample` and `randperm` but neither of them seems to include this option.

Comment: How do you know which values to exclude? You might want to first create a temporary vector that does not contain the value(s) you want to exclude, and then draw randomly from it (You could, for example, randomly draw an index)

Comment: Hi Bill, thanks for the suggestion. I think excluding directly from the original vector would be easier, if that possibility exists, since I have many possible exclusion combinations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I found a way to do it.

For a string vector, it can be done using `erase` function. For example:

```
cues_minusR = erase (cues,'R');
```

For a number vector (e.g., `cues = [1 2 3 4 5 6]`), it works this way:

```
c1Col=1;
c2Col=2;
cues(c1Col, : ) = [];
cues([c1Col, c2Col], : ) = [];
```

Answer (score 4):

One intuitive way to achieve this would be taking your lists of all values and exclusions, and making a list of *inclusions* instead, then you can select from that list.

See the comments for each step:

```
cues= ["R" "B" "C" "P" "Y" "G"]; % All options
exclude = ["R" "Y"];             % Exclusions (could change in a loop or whatever)
include = setdiff( cues, exclude ); % Actual options without exclusions
selection = include( randi(numel(include)) ); % Random selection from options
```

Comment: something tells me that the question requires some additional clarification

Comment: @JohnBG why do you say that? Seems a direct question with a direct answer

Comment: the question originator mentions that thought it was easy but it turns it's not. When I read the question I have the impression that something is missing. That 'in second condition' needs clarification.